# Relation between Coulomb's law and Fine-structure constant

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, coulombs-law, physical-constants

There should be some relationship between them due to the nature of FSC, but I could not find anything about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yet it was clear enough for @Dale to give an excellent answer. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can rearrange the definition of the fine structure constant $$\alpha = \frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 \hbar c}$$ to get $$\alpha \frac{4\pi \epsilon_0 \hbar c}{e^2}=1$$ Then we can multiply Coulomb’s law by $1$ to get $$F=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}\alpha \frac{4\pi \epsilon_0 \hbar c}{e^2}$$ $$F=\alpha \hbar c \frac{n_1 n_2}{r^2}$$ where $n_i=q_i/e$ is the dimensionless number of fundamental charges in $q_i$.

So the fine structure constant can be used to write Coulomb’s law in terms where the charge is given as a dimensionless count of the number of electrons. Meaning that the force is related to the number of charges.